# I want to mention a singular platform but imply impact of plural things. Can I use this in the sentence?

Tags: grammar, plural-forms, singular

Platforms like this are very helpful.
Or should I have to use "these"?

Answer (score 4):

You would only say "these" if you had referred to more than one example.

You said that you have mentioned a singular platform, so you should say "other platforms like **this**".

The fact that 'platforms' is plural makes it clear that there are *others* like this *one*.